# IIS looking at wrong path for MVC configuration file

Tags: nhibernate, iis, config, andromda

When I run MVC4 my application using Visual Studio Development Server, my application is able to load all configuration files correctly. But when I try to run it under the Local IIS Web server, it throws this error

```
{"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\inetsrv\\~\\nhibernate.config'."}
```

It's looking at the wrong folder. The config file is directly in the root of my web project. Why is this happening. How can I fix it. I'm pretty sure that nhibernate looks for this file in order to load it's properties. Unless you know **how** to move nhibernate configuration files into the web.config file, please don't recommend that, I get a "Unrecognized configuration section hibernate-configuration" when ever I copy it over

Edit:
by the way, I'm pretty sure it's looking at the following key in appSettings my app settings section

```
<add key="nhibernate.config" value="~/nhibernate.config" />
```

Edit2:
here is the stack trace that goes into how Nhibernate is getting this value, and trying to find the configuration file

```
at NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration..ctor(XmlReader hbConfigurationReader, Boolean fromAppSetting)
at NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSchema.HibernateConfiguration..ctor(XmlReader hbConfigurationReader)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(XmlReader textReader)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(String fileName, Boolean ignoreSessionFactoryConfig)
at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Configure(String fileName)
at AndroMDA.NHibernateSupport.DefaultSessionManager.BuildSessionFactory()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it wasn't actually NHibernate that was using this file. My boss decided to use something called AndroMDA to generate code, and part of that generation was some NHibernate Support that I couldn't see into.

If anybody is interested, I created a new implementation of ISessionManager, which looks exactly like DefaultSessionManager except for the following member function and variable.

```
public class ServerMapSessionManager : ISessionManager
{
    //other interface implementation...//
    public static HttpServerUtility Server { get; set; }
    public String TranslateConfigPath(String virtualPath)
    {
        return Server.MapPath("/"+virtualPath);
    }
}
```

Then in App_start I call the following

```
        SessionManagerFactory.SessionManager = new MVCFramework.Core.Common.ServerMapSessionManager();
        MVCFramework.Core.Common.ServerMapSessionManager.Server = Server;
```